# Blazor Server InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: } on .NET 7

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor server app targetting .NET 7 sdk. I have these sdks installed currently:

```
.NET SDK 7.0.305 x64
.NET SDK 6.0.411 x64
```

I am pulling down a completely new blazor server template, with docker enabled and https disabled, with solution and project in the same directory.

If I set `<UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>` in my project file, the app will load (but hot reload is disabled)

When I set that value to true, the app opens with an Internal Server Error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }.
```

Full stack:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DynamicPageEndpointMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? All of the resources I've found were for Blazor that uses the Startup.cs template, and even though I was able to recreate their advice nothing seems to resolve it. I also have not moved my _Host.cshtml file out of the Pages folder.

Comment: `<UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>` was added to force the compilation to Net5 behaviour i.e. opt out of the new Net6 source compilers. There were issues with chaining source generators  I don't know what setting it to true does.  What happens when you remove it?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis when it's removed, that's when the error occurs. When that line is present the app builds and runs fine, but hot reload does not work.

Comment: So "I am pulling down a completely new blazor server template, with docker enabled and https disabled, with solution and project in the same directory".  You create a solution from a standard template and it doesn't compile?

Comment: It compiles, but when running and opening the local host site, I get an exception on the site itself

Comment: It works on my machines (and a lot of other people's) otherwise it would have been fixed by MS long ago.  You have a local machine configuration issue, that without access to the machine it's almost impossible to solve.  I don't know where to point you next.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue. Updating visual studio to 17.6.5 and creating a new project fixed it for me.